# QuickCheck test randomly hangs

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm new to Haskell. I'm playing with QuickCheck tests, trying to test a simple function `calculateStrengthSingle` (see the source of testee below)

```
# Fighter.hs
module Fighter
( Quantity(Quantity)
, Fighter(TeamPlayer, LoneWolf, Polymorph)
, Strength(Strength)
, calculateStrengthSingle)
where

import System.Random

data Strength = Strength Double

instance Eq Strength where
    Strength s1 == Strength s2 =
        s1 == s2

instance Ord Strength where
    Strength s1 < Strength s2 =
        s1 < s2

data Quantity = Quantity Int deriving (Show)

instance Random Quantity where
    randomR (Quantity lo, Quantity hi) g =
        let rand = randomR (lo, hi) g
            (r, g1) = rand
        in (Quantity r, g1)
    random g =
        let rand = random g
            (r, g1) = rand
        in (Quantity r, g1)

data Fighter = TeamPlayer
             | LoneWolf
             | Polymorph
    deriving (Show)


calculateStrengthSingle :: Quantity -> Fighter -> Strength
calculateStrengthSingle (Quantity number) TeamPlayer =
    Strength(log (fromIntegral number))
calculateStrengthSingle _ _ = Strength 0.0
```

The test looks like this

```
# TestFighter.hs
import qualified Test.QuickCheck as QuickCheck
import Fighter

prop_StrengthPositive quantity fighter =
    Fighter.calculateStrengthSingle quantity fighter >= Strength 0.0

instance QuickCheck.Arbitrary Fighter.Fighter where
    arbitrary = QuickCheck.oneof([return Fighter.TeamPlayer, return Fighter.LoneWolf, return Fighter.Polymorph])

instance QuickCheck.Arbitrary Fighter.Quantity where
    arbitrary = QuickCheck.choose(Fighter.Quantity 1, Fighter.Quantity 10)

main :: IO()
main = do
    QuickCheck.quickCheck prop_StrengthPositive
```

When I do `runhaskell TestFighter.hs` there's output `(1 test)` (the number is changing, sometimes it's `0` other times it's `4`) and CPU is 100% loaded. Nothing happens for a minute or so. When I interrupt the program by `Ctrl+C`, it spits out something like

```
^C*** Failed! Exception: 'user interrupt' (after 1 test):  
Quantity 2
TeamPlayer
```

**Questions:**

1. Where did I mess up?
2. How can I debug cases of infinite calculation, like this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't defined the `Ord` instance for `Strength` correctly. You need to define `<=` and not `<`.

With only `<` defined the function `<=` enters into an infinite loop as it is defined in terms of `compare` and `compare` is defined in terms of `<=`. Minimal definition needs to define either `compare` or `<=`.

Here is the fixed code for `Ord` instance

```
instance Ord Strength where
    Strength s1 <= Strength s2 =
        s1 <= s2
```

Comment: What about debugging such stuff? How can I figure out what do I miss?

Comment: There is no general way of doing that. What I usually do is to use `verboseCheck` instead of `quickCheck` to see what are the tests it is failing on and then try to go through the test manually. That is how I found the `Ord` instance was the culprit in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running your test with `-o 1` as a parameter, which causes a timeout after one second. It can then display the input that caused your program to hang. Its doesn't tell you exactly where the problem is, but its a good start.

**EDIT**: this is how I use test framework with cabal

```
test-Suite runTests
   hs-source-dirs:      src, test
   type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
   main-is:             RunTests.hs
   other-modules:
                       <...>

  build-depends:       base >= 3 && < 5,
                       HUnit,
                       test-framework,
                       test-framework-th,
                       test-framework-hunit,
                       test-framework-quickcheck2,
                       QuickCheck,
```

To be complete in my description, I build using:

```
cabal-dev install --enable-tests
```

Comment: In my GHC, `-o` is setting filename, not timeout

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I use -o 1 as a runtime parameter, but I also use quickcheck wrapped with test-framework, so there may be a discrepancy between options here. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework

Comment: if you'd like to go down the test-framework road, look at test-framework-th, this minimises typing.

Comment: Maybe you can also link me a way to integrate the `test-framework` with `cabal test`? It seems like `cabal` only supports HUnit and QuickCheck by themselves, not the unifying `test-framework`.